# How can I force native MathML on Wikipedia pages in Firefox's Reader view?

Tags: firefox, css, mathml

I've been using the [Native MathML extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/native-mathml/) to make Wikipedia use MathML for its formulas. It worked fine, until I turned on the Firefox's Reader View (I'm using Firefox 67). In that mode, I selected a dark theme, and all the formulas appeared to not only be image-based (which would be a minor problem), but also black — on dark background, which seriously impairs readability.

I then tried following the [Wikipedia's *Displaying a formula* guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Native_MathML) and created my user page `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:MyUserName/common.css` (where `MyUserName` is replaced with actual name; this is by following [*User style* help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:User_style)), where I placed the recommended [CSS code from *Native MathML*](https://github.com/fred-wang/webextension-native-mathml/blob/master/content-scripts/mediawiki.css).

This worked normally — in normal mode. In Reader View this still failed — as if Firefox simply ignores all the CSS on the page in this mode.

I've also tried following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1323420/87525) to add the CSS rules into the Reader view, but that was only respected in non-Reader mode, and Reader ignored this again.

So, how can I make Wikipedia actually show the MathML formulas in Firefox's Reader View?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Reader view simply strips all the `<math>` tags from the Wikipedia pages, so indeed no stylesheet would help in getting MathML formulas show.

Instead, to get dark Wikipedia with white MathML formulas, I have now installed the [*Dark Mode* Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-mode-webextension) — in addition to *Native MathML*. Just have to keep away from the Reader mode on Wikipedia.